# NodeJS child_process exec function unable to run command?

Tags: node.js, linux, child-process, systemctl

I'm trying to run a command in my node app as follows:

```
var command = `aspera ats download -H ${HOST} -u ${USER} -p ${PWD} -s ${link} -d ${PATH}`
var asperaDownload = exec(command)
```

Where `exec` is: `var exec = require('child_process').exec`

However, I'm receiving the following error:

```
[4873]: child stderr:
[4873]: /bin/sh: aspera: command not found
[4873]: child process exited with code 127 and signal null
```

My node app is running in a Linux environment, and runs as a `systemctl` process.

I can see the error above when I run my `systemctl status` command, which displays the node app's output.

NOTE: In that same shell window, if I run the command `aspera` on its own, the shell is able to recognize the command.

Do I need to register this command somewhere else for my node app to recognize it?

Comment: The command needs to be in your `$PATH`. You can specify the absolute path to it instead, i.e. `/path/to/aspera ats download ....`. If you used `${PATH}` in your command because you assigned the destination path to this variable, you've overridden the shell search path which would be why it doesn't work

Comment: I changed the variable name and I'm still encountering the same error. I've also added the following: `PATH=$PATH:$HOME/.aspera/cli/bin` to my `bash_profile` file, but I believe I need to be including this as part of `bin`, not `bash`?

Comment: Just specify `/home/youruser/.aspera/cli/bin/aspera ats ....`

Comment: Irrelevant to my original question but I'm now getting a `permission denied` error, despite running `chmod 777` on `aspera`...